# Equals for domain class in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The following equals code returns wrong result for domain

```
boolean equals(o) {
  if (o == null) return false
  if (this.is(o)) return true
  getClass() == o.class && id == o.id
}
```

For two loaded entities with same id return false. Id are equals (one record in DB). But classes not same.

The entities -- fields in another domains. And it looks like GORM used some wrapper classes.

How to avoid this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is special method in GormInstanceApi

```
/**
 * Proxy aware instanceOf implementation.
 */
boolean instanceOf(D o, Class cls) {
    if (o instanceof EntityProxy) {
        o = (D)((EntityProxy)o).getTarget()
    }
    return o in cls
}
```

Using of this method solved problem

Answer (score 0):

As you are seeing, requiring that the classes be the same is overly strict. Using `instanceof` is usually safer, e.g.

```
class Foo {
    boolean equals(o) {
        if (!o) return false
        if (is(o)) return true
        o instanceof Foo && id == o.id
    }
}
```

Using `id` in `equals` or `hashCode` is generally a bad idea in domain classes since you can't compare persistent and non-persistent classes. For example

```
class Foo {
    String name
    boolean equals(o) {
        if (!o) return false
        if (is(o)) return true
        o instanceof Foo && id == o.id
    }
}
```

With this class, this would fail:

```
new Foo(name: 'foo').save()
assert Foo.findByName('foo') == new Foo(name: 'foo')
```

but all of the important class data (in this case just the `name` property) is identical in both cases.

Even worse, assuming you create a `hashCode` method that's similarly broken, if you add a non-persistent instance to a hash-based collection (e.g. `HashSet`) and then save it, its `id` will change from null to some long value and so will its hashcode value. This will cause the instance to become "lost" in the collection.

Comment: you can't compare persistent and non-persistent classes -- I know. But it limited by business logic

Comment: When using instanceof, you need to know the class of "B" at compile time. When using isAssignableFrom() it can be dynamic and change during runtime.
B.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass())